# Emphasize inline verbatim text (with \verb or equivalent)

Tags: verbatim

How can I emphasize inline verbatim text? `\emph{\verb|$Text|}` creates an error. Nothing else I tried works either, e.g. \Verb. Is there any easy way to do this? I would need all kinds of special latex characters in the verbatim text (which contains program code fragments), not only "$".

Of course one can do `\emph{\$Text}`. But having to escape every single special character takes a lot of time and changes the highlighted program code fragment in the latex source file, which is not desirable.

Comment: Try `\makeatletter\renewcommand\verbatim@font{\ttfamily}\makeatother` and then use `{\em \verb|$Text|}` instead. Also, show us a compilable example of your document.

Comment: @Phelype, this works. I tried it with all special characters I can think of at the moment. The drawback is, that in my text system (TeXStudio) the edit (autocomplete) macro for \verb does not work correctly any more and it becomes very complicated to type it. So basically I cannot use plain \verb any more. Not all inline verbatim text is to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fancyvrb`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\Verb|$Text$|

\Verb[fontshape=it]|$Text|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A nice and simple solution, thanks a lot. However, I get the same problems with my editor (TeXStudio) as described for the answer by Steven B. Segletes: the editor gets skrewed up by taking the $ inside of \Verb as the opening of a math environment. Since this does not happen with \verb, I imagine this could be adapted in the editor somehow.

Comment: @RolandSalz Ask the support of TeXStudio.

Comment: @RolandSalz As far as I can see, `\verb` and `\verb*` are treated specially in the source code for the program, so I don't see a way to add other “verbatim” exceptions without a new version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your investigation. Well, let's leave the issue as it is for the moment. For the time being I will stick with escaping individual characters in a normal, emphasized text string. Your solution probably is the easiest one within the scope of latex, the rest is a text editor problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach with `verbatimbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
Here is emphasized
\begin{verbbox}[\itshape]
$Text\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox{}
to be shown inline.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{preview}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
With the last line I get an error message: Package listofitems Error: The \expanded primitive is not provided by your TeX engine. What's wrong here?

Comment: @RolandSalz The core of TeX/LaTeX was upgraded in December 2018 to make use of the `\expanded` command as a primitive.  The `listofitems` package was upgraded to take advantage of that.  However, if you still have an old engine, `listofitems` should load a prior version of itself that does not rely on `\expanded`.  So, hopefully, the error message is more "informative" rather than "debilitating."  Best solution: upgrade your LaTeX installation.  See documentation at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listofitems

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and your hint. Now it works. But the next problem is, that my latex editor (TeXStudio) does not understand this construction properly and takes the $ inside of the verbbox as the beginning of a mathmode environment, with the end missing. Thus, the rest of the source code is screwd up in the editor. I am tempted to give up...

Comment: @RolandSalz Working with verbatim can definitely wreak havoc on text editors that expect a non-verbatim syntax..